# Font errors in console when using IBM Carbon Design System in React

Tags: reactjs, vite, carbon-design-system

I'm quite new to React and am trying to use IBM Carbon's Design system for some simple components, but I keep on getting the following console errors:

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: <URL>
OTS parsing error: invalid sfntVersion: 1008813135
```

Steps that I followed:

1. I installed the DS with `npm install --save @carbon/react` as well as Scss with `npm install sass`
2. I renamed `App.css` and `index.css` to `.scss` and both of their contents are just `@use "@carbon/react";`

From what I've Googled it seems to be an error with finding the fonts, but the IBM docs also mention that I don't need to install the fonts separately as they're included with the React components.

Thanks in advance!

Ps. I'm usint Vite React TS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out by finding a vite example on GitHub. The `index.css` file needs to have the following contents:

```
@use '@carbon/react' with (
  $font-path: '@ibm/plex'
);
```

and not what I had before which was simply:

```
@use '@carbon/react'
```